# MVC Validation Foolproof

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am rebulding existing portal from web forms to MVC and I have problem with validation. I have something like this model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [RequiredIf("FirstNameRequired", true)]        
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool FirstNameRequired { get; set; }
    public bool FirstNameVisible { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("LastNameRequired", true)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool LastNameRequired { get; set; }
    public bool LastNameVisible { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("EmailRequired", true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailRequired { get; set; }
    public bool EmailVisible { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalInfo
{
    public Customer PrimaryCustomer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

There are many properties in the customer  but i added 3 just for example(like 100 or something).
I am doing this way because there are many contact types and properties like visible and required are dinamyc. Now I have editor template that will render all customers. It goes something like this.

```
@if (Model.FirstNameVisible)
{ 
    <p>
        First Name:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
    </p>
}
@if (Model.LastNameVisible)
{ 
    <p>
        Last Name:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
    </p>
}
@if (Model.EmailVisible)
{ 
    <p>
        Email:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    </p>
}
```

Now this is rendering all contacts but when i post data in the model REQUIRED and VISIBLE boolean properties are false. These is because i didn't add:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FirstNameRequired)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FirstNameVisible)
```

If I add this validation is working good. ModelState.IsValid is working corectly.
The problem is what if someone change hidden value data and will be able to insert incorect data. How can i prevent this?

Comment: You may want to add a tag for the language you are using, help attract the right knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[RequiredIf(...)]` with plain `[Required]` and remove `@Html.HiddenFor(...)`.
This will make the fields always required and users must supply values.

You will have to manually validate fields that are variably required before persisting the entity.

Comment: The problem is not always all properties are required. If FirstNameRequired == bool then firstname should be required, same for all other properties.

Comment: In that case you should validate the model before inserting it into the database

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492767%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
And so your model will be validated using a token.

an other solution would be to manually check that the user is allowed to insert the data.

On the sideline for validation you can always use  [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc).